# SQLExpress create relationship between two tables

Tags: database, sql-server-express

I have 2 tables.

1. dbo.Department
2. dbo.Employee Records

In employee records, I have a field 2 important fields.

1. Employee ID (Set as my primary Key)
2. Department ID

In Department, I only have 3 fields

1. Department ID (set as my primary key)
2. Name
3. Location

I want Department ID to be populated with data from dbo.Department so the only options are a pull down list. (EXAMPLE department 100 - Marketing - Floor 1, department 200 - Human Resources - Floor 2 ETC.) To do this, I attempted to create a new foreign key in dbo.Department

First, I right clicked on the keys folder in dbo.Department and selected 'New Foreign Key'

Then, I clicked on the 3 dots I got when I selected the 'Tables and Columns Specific' field as shown below.

[image: SQL Picture One]

This pops up a dialog box where I can set the Primary Key table and the foreign key table. I set the primary key table as Employee Records and the foreign key table as Department. Under both fields, I have Department ID selected as shown below. [image: SQL Dialog box]

When I hit ok I get the following message

'The columns in table "Employee Records" do not match a primary key or UNIQUE constraint'

Am I setting this up wrong? I'm new to database practices so I'm not sure if I'm even using the right technique to do what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, but have your tables reversed.  Create your foreign key on the Employees table, not the Departments table.  The primary key table in this case is the Departments table.

Comment: This did it. Thank you. Enjoy your bounty.

Comment: I apologize. I thought hitting the check mark awarded the bounty.

Comment: I would have thought that too.